# Android adMob Displaying in the Middle of Screen

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob

I am trying to display an adMob Ad Banner a the top of the screen. However, as seen below, it is displaying in the middle. Anyone know how I can fix this?

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ndroid:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="30dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mnwvbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/mnwvicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/reportsbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/reportsicon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mnwvshowbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/showicon"
        android:paddingTop="30dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is where I add the AdView the my LinearLayout in my code:

```
    // Admob Banner ***********
    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14ed285a63276d");
    layout.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());   
    // *************************
```

Here is what appears on my screen:

[image]

Comment: Short answer: @+id/linearLayout is used twice in you layout xml, try give the inner one another name, This should fix your problem.

Comment: @yorkw sorry that was a copy paste error... in my code it wasnt actually like that. I edited my question and forgot to take it out of the parent LinearLayout. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use relativ layout. In the following layout, based on yours, the ad layout has for id "adLayout":

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ndroid:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/adLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/adLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="30dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  [...]
```

Comment: thanks! I ended up having to do this and then using the Graphical Layout to set the appropriate location of the icons. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

The linearLayout you're adding to is the parent element; the whole screen. Try adding a child linear layout to it (another linear layout completely contained within the main one) and set android:gravity="bottom".

Here's an example without the buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Or relative parent (The styles include just basic sizing. Parent fills screen, child wraps ad.):

```
<RelativeLayout 
style="@style/FPFP">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ads"
    style="@style/WCWC"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i made the changes you asked for and changed my question. the image in my question is what I get now. (I know the XML does not have the android:gravity="bottom", but it gives almost the same thing.)

Comment: When I've done this in the past I've actually made the parent element a relative layout and the ad container a linear layout with 'android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"'. I'll add that example code at the end of my answer.